# A forcefield only penetrable by humans?

Tags: science-fiction, post-apocalypse

In the not-too-far-away future during a nuclear winter, one city survived by being sealed under a dome forcefield (?) protecting them from the cold weather and potentially harmful sunrays once the sky cleared up.

Robots with varying degrees of complexity exist in this world, and I don't want them to be able to enter this dome. I thought that the forcefield could be electromagnetic to prevent machines from entering.
But a group of humans that my story follows has to be able to penetrate this dome. So how could I make the field separate the inside from the outside and still allow humans to enter?

The humans that I follow are also bringing in mechanical gear that, in order to further my plot, needs to be rendered useless as they enter.

I am very much open to better scenarios if it proves too difficult to make plausible or is too far fetched. I am a bit unsure if the technology the dome uses fits with the technological level of the city it covers.

Comment: What do you mean by "mechanical gear"?  Crowbars, block and tackle, electric winch, gas welding equipment...?

Comment: More like mechanical armour :)

Comment: **Clarification request:** (a) the shield won't permit atmosphere below a specific temperature to enter (problem: how to breathe during the winter). (b) the shield won't permit photons having a wavelength shorter than 400nm (problem: vitamin-D deficiency). (c) Nothing robotic can pass through the shield (problem: nothing metal, ceramic, rubber, or plastic can pass, how did the robots get out?). (d) Humans can pass through. (e) Their mechanized equipment is deactivated (problem: nothing electrical can pass unless it's very low-level, like human brains).

Comment: Very few cities are self-sufficient at food production. Is this dome hundreds of kilometers across to include the necessary farming areas?

Comment: Have you considered just putting metal detectors and security personnel at each entrance?  Works for airports, courthouses, government buildings, etc.

Comment: What level of complexity have the robots ? Are they an advanced AI that can came up with solutions or they are only capable to follow a (more or less complex) program ? In the first case you probably cannot keep them out as they would find a solution (an underground tunnel for example)

Comment: Do machines, robots, and "mechanical gear" exist and work INSIDE the dome? In other words, is everything electrical/electronic/mechanical useless inside the dome, or just what crosses the dome?

Comment: if they are advanced enough to build force fields they can build AI smart enough to tell a human from a robot and only let humans in.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact (a) What I had in mind was that the city would be using geothermal energy to heat up the inside and get most of their energy this way (b) for the vitamin D deficiency problem I thought about inserting huge light poles large enough to emit light that mimics the sun and help with agriculture (c) the robots were never inside, there was another city that survived and the two cities (both with great weapon defences) would be in a cold war scenario passively fighting for which society and ideology would lead humanity's future.

Comment: @user535733 Yes, the domed area would be big enough to room farms for agriculture

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I didn't envision the dome having any entrances or exits per se, but that could be something to consider

Comment: @Gianluca The robots in the story would appear not to be more advanced than service robots and peace keepers, but as the story progress the main characters would eventually find out that they can be more human acting and appearing (like in Westworld). There is an AI present in the story that has been programmed to look after humanity's survival and best self interests, that has taken the leadership role of the other surviving city, although programmed in such a way as to never being able to reach singularity, because of all the unseen consequences it could bring. (1/2)

Comment: @Gianluca I imagined the humans creating the robots, but think the AI could have something to do with it. I'm not 100% sure how everything is going to play out just yet, but what you're saying is true, I'm just struggling to find a believable way to make the human characters the best and/or only way to infiltrate the domed city (2/2)

Comment: @JoshPart Yes, inside the dome power and electricity exists, the main characters' objective after they enter is to find a power source to recharge their mechanical armour

Comment: @John I suppose they could, but not sure how that would be done if the dome covers a huge range of fields and forests. I guess the field maybe could differentiate between organic and inorganic material?

Comment: @Rednas Thank you! Please remember to [edit] your post with these details. You should never trust that people will read through comments. The comment chains can get quite long.

Comment: @Rednas its a force field, you right the rules for it. Who says the entire field has to have the same properties or even the same origin.

Comment: Can you clarify "electromagnetic to prevent machines from entering" being a problem, as against "humans have to be able to penetrate…"? How could it be a problem to "separate the inside from the outside"?

Comment: Welcome Rednas, this is the wrong use of the reality-check tag. If you create your force field and detail it for us, we can “check” if it makes sense. Could you please remove that tag, or adjust the question?

Answer (score 17):

**CAPTCHA Palisade**

[image]

The dome itself does nothing. Only it is hard to find. The directions to get to the dome are based on identifying bridges, cars, traffic, lights. For example "turn left at the traffic lights, go straight ahead until you pass

[image]

parked cars, then left under the bridge. . . "

Robots are notoriously bad at following this sort of directions. They always get lost.

Comment: On an ...unrelated note, what is "1 + 3"?

Comment: Smart. But this doesn't solve to electrical gear problem.

Comment: I have just joined this community from core stack overflow just to give you +1 for this ridiculous answer

Answer (score 10):

[image: loki]

"The machine would melt you from the inside out.  Please move along, sir."

---

There are robots.  The people who built the dome don't want robots getting in.  There is a robot Guardianoutside the dome that guards the entrance (which is a bridge, because).  The robot Guardian does not let robots through.  It does not let anything that might be a robot through.  Mechanical gear might be a robot.

The dome is pretty sweet.  The Guardian is pretty scary.  The humans in your group don't understand how either one works but it is clear that both do, well.

Comment: What colour is the Robot Guardian though?

Comment: @Daron - depends on the season.

Answer (score 10):

## The forcefield can already solve this

The forcefield is much like what is used in Star Wars by the Gungangs in the movie 'the phantom menace'. It holds anything at bay over a certain speed/pressure, but slower less high pressure like a human or air can still go through.

This forcefield however has an electromagnetic effect against anything that passes through. Anyone with experience with Magnetic Resonance Imaging (MRI) machines can tell you it can be disorientating, nauseating or just plain weird, but it isn't dangerous. However, for anything electronic it is incredibly dangerous. Humans pass through, robots aren't as lucky.

Comment: Having never seen the phantom menace, that description sounds *quite* a lot like the way shields work in the Dune universe. Would that be a good comparison?

Comment: I already feel bad for cyborgs of your universe, which includes people with cardiostimulators.

Comment: @Hearth I'm not familiar with Dune shields, but a quick read shows that this can be how they work. The details can still be done by the author, but something like this seems suitable.

Comment: @valisstillwithMonica don't be. They are either happy to be alive or happy to be an awesome cyborg. We all have some limitations that are difficult to overcome.

Answer (score 6):

## There's an electromagnetic pulse at each entrance.

This fries any electronics or robots, but leaves humans unharmed. Robots can enter the place physically, but are immediately fried.

Comment: It's possible to shield a device against an EMP.  This might take out the wimpy service droids, but a hardened battlebot would just walk right through it unperturbed.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That is a problem. I think a cool solution would be to say that the field passes through solid matter, and so the EMP happens continually while passing through, and originates within the robot, bypassing shielding. As with any security measure, there are likely ways to bypass it, but they may be unknown/impractical.

Comment: Most things designed to shield against emps have a limited ability to resist it, and will be overwhelmed in time. If a giant warbot with a thick faraday cage skin comes in it'll be fine until the people inside shoot some holes in the cage, but it may well be that most robots in this world aren't build well enough to handle this emp.

Comment: Also, an EMP could damage human nuclei in cells. Just saying.

Comment: @CarterLang If it's very, very high intensity, maybe, but I'd be more worried about human eyeballs and skin in that case.

Answer (score 2):

**You could have running water at each entrance**

i.e. Shower, waterfall. Shorts out any electric gear or bot. Water-proof robots are probably not equipped for land travel, but hey, it's your story!

**Also**

**Long-term ionization**

*To take out the water-proof bots that got through.* Although an electromagnetic pulse (meaning all at once) strong enough to damage electronics would potentially affect human genetics in their cells. **But**, if the whole inside of the dome was washed with ionized particles at regular intervals, the longer, weaker doses would affect electronics well before humans. The only problems would be

1. Knowing when to stop,
2. The water-proof bots would have access to the city for a short, but still substantial period of time.

Technically, whatever you say goes, but I don't know if the logistics would work out. The water would have to be externally drawn, which means it has been under the outside radiation. To draw the water from inside would require a large reservoir. It could work. Your choice.

Comment: Should not be an umbrella or a plastic sheet sufficient to make a robot water proof ? (Assuming they can come up with such solution of course)

Comment: I'm thinking more like a spray from all sides.

Comment: A robot does not need to breath. You can wrap up in plastic and it is good. I mean, we have dry suit, water does not seems to be a great deterrent

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps all the robots and the equipment require a satellite connection to work, but the dome contains a metal plane or mesh

As long as that sky connection is needed, even a thin layer of conductive material is sufficient to act as a [faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage), preventing successful connection to the outside world, rendering the robots inert and the gear useless

Rebar is not a tight enough grid (the communication waves must not fit through the gaps), but a tighter grid (like a microwave door) or shell could be explained away by explicit purpose

Perhaps the robots are not entrusted by a larger system with enough intelligence to go around on batteries (and thus enter the dome), require a connection to some [Multivax](https://www.physics.princeton.edu/ph115/LQ.pdf)-sized ground unit, simply have no apparent motive and go about their inscrutable tasks ignoring the dome, or were really created by the dome-dwellers, and know to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

The shield is active - in the computational sense. There is a field around the city from which information like MRI can be extracted to determine the structure of anything passing through the region. The field can also be ramped up to the point that it destroys something by internal heating. The control over this is detailed. Most likely, by default things get fried. But, if you, a human, approach slowly enough to be identified as human, then the security system fries your equipment, but lets you through. In principle the business end of the security system might be able to supply enough power to break any material into ions.

Answer (score 0):

**strong magnetic field on the ground**
Powerful magnetic coils powered by cold fusion could essentially repel any robot similar to how maglev rail repel the train, turning it into a brick wall for all robots. If a piece of electronic equipment does get too close, the coil would damage the CPU (Similar to how MRI supermagnets damage hard drive data) which also solves your problem of needing the field to shut down electronics.